# ¿Qué diferencias hay entre estos procedimientos?

Tags: javascript

El programa consiste en un simple onKeyUp, escribir en un input un texto y que este se escriba al mismo tiempo en un párrafo del documento. Presento dos formas de realizarlo, las cuales llevan a la misma solución. No obstante no entiendo el procedimiento de la primera forma. ¿En que consiste javascript:databinding(this) y (elem)?

## HTML

```
//Primera forma

 Tu texto:
<input type="text" id="texto" onKeyUp="javascript:dataBinding(this);">
<br>
<p id="textonuevo">
</p>

//Segunda forma

 Tu texto:
<input type="text" id="texto" onKeyUp="up()";
<br>
<p id="texto nuevo">
</p>
```

### Javascript

```
//Primera forma

function dataBinding(elem){
var titulo=elem.value; 
document.getElementById('textonuevo').innerHTML=titulo;
}

//Segunda forma

function up() {
var titulo=texto.value;
document.getElementById('textonuevo').innerHTML=titulo;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el primer caso, estas pasando con el `this` el elemento del que tomas el valor, que luego será la variable `elem` en la función.

En el segundo caso, el elemento del que tomas el texto es estático y definido dentro de la función.

El método `databinding(elem)` es "reutilizable" y podrías usarlo si tuvieras que ejecutar cierta acción en diversos inputs.

El `javascript:` puede eliminarse en la llamada y te quedaría directamente como una función más. Quizás eso te haya descolocado.

Comment: Gracias,ya entiendo el uso del this y elem, pero no me queda muy claro eso de "reutilizable"  ¿Algun ejemplo sencillo en el que usar la primera forma en vez de la segunda?

Comment: Imagina una función en la que te dicen que en lugar de que solo se puede añadir el texto desde un solo campo, pudieras añadirlo desde 3 campos diferentes, pero todos van a hacer lo mismo. Si pasas el elem, siempre cogerás el valor de ese campo que estas editando en el keyup, y no tendrás que escribir tres métodos distintos para cada uno de los campos.

Es un ejemplo sencillo que se me ocurre, pero tiene muchísimas utilidades. Hasta que no se te da una, no se me ocurre... Pero al menos que sepas que se puede hacer así para llegado el caso, poder solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Perfecto ¡¡ Ya lo veo claro. Muchas gracias.